# How can i auto-scroll cursor to an current date of current month in fullcalendar

Tags: javascript, jquery

When I am usgin a fullcalendar (jQuery plugin) page made by me for my project I need the page to auto-scroll to the current date. For that I am trying to use fullcalendar's `gotoDate` function but it's not working properly:

```
viewRender: function(currentView) {
  //console.log('view Render');

  var scrollTime = moment().format("HH:mm:ss");
  $('#calendar').fullCalendar({
    now: '2018-05-21',
    scrollTime: scrollTime
  })

  // $('#calendar').fullCalendar('refetchEvents' )
  $('#calendar').fullCalendar('gotoDate', '2018-05-21');    
}
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

fullCalendar scrollTime doc:

> Determines how far forward the scroll pane is initially scrolled.
>
> Duration, default: '06:00:00' (6am)

And you actually are not giving a time. try:

```
var scrollTime = moment('12:00:00').format("HH:mm:ss");
```

fullCalendar accepts a Moment as second parameter you are giving as string, but not formatted.
Doc say that it accepts anything that Moment constructor accepts, so it should be right done but you could be more specific giving the format.

you can try:

```
$('#calendar').fullCalendar('gotoDate', moment('2018-05-21').format("YYYY-MM-DD"));
```

scrollTime is used to scroll to a time of the day. If you are intended to scroll specific day (p.e because calendar does not show full in your screen) I dont know if 'gotodate' actually has it behaviour. In other case you could use scroll animation for this

```
$('html, body').animate({
    scrollTop: ($('#element').offset().top)
},500);
```

Also fullcalendar provide us functions to manage month and year changes.
For example for next month ([Next doc](https://fullcalendar.io/docs/next)):

```
$('#my-next-button').click(function() {
  $('#calendar').fullCalendar('next');
});
```

In some cases we can attach to an element and detect if user scrolled totally down of that element, then change month: (We need to know the element that has to be scrolled or attach to the element that fills with our desired behaviour)

```
jQuery(function($) {
    $('#element-with-scroll').on('scroll', function() {
        if($(this).scrollTop() + $(this).innerHeight() >= $(this)[0].scrollHeight) {
             $('#calendar').fullCalendar('next');
        }
    })
});
```

Let us know how it progress.

Comment: if i use gotoDate function then it will block my calendar in only current month.means if i want change the month eg. next month or previous month it will show only current date month. and i want to scroll the scroller of fullcalendar to an current date of current month. is there any other way to do this..?

Comment: Actually doc does not talk about that behaviour. But still you can configure prev, next, nextYear, prevYear actions. check here: https://fullcalendar.io/docs/prev , https://fullcalendar.io/docs/next ... I dont see exactly what you mean but Im sure you can manage to have it as you expect with that.